# Change Django-Rest-Framework serializer from flat to nested?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

As per this example of nested and flat:

https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/serialization/

I want the foreign key to represented from the following JSON output

```
{
        "cart": {
            "cartid": "C0001",
            "username": "myuser1"
        },
        "subtotal": 150.0,
        "start_day": "2019-03-20T00:00:00"
    },
```

to be represented like:

```
{
            "C0001": {
                "username": "myuser1"
            },
            "subtotal": 150.0,
            "start_day": "2019-03-20T00:00:00"
        },
```

Is there a simple way to have this output in django-rest-framework?

Here are my serializers:

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='shopper.username')    
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['shopper', 'cartid', 'username']


class CartProdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cart = CartSerializer(read_only=True, label=Cart.cartid)
    class Meta:
        model = cart_prod
        fields = ['cart', 'subtotal', 'start_day']
```

And my view:

```
class CartProdView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = cart_prod.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartProdSerializer
```

Comment: it will be good if you add your code of the models

Comment: nothings stops you from overriding the serializer `to_representation()` method and, if you're also going to write, the `to_internal_value()` method (see [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#baseserializer))

Comment: Great thanks I don't know if you want to give it as an answer or I can just delete the question...